# Why does destructuring an argument object affect it's 'this' value?

Tags: javascript, scope, this, destructuring

Can someone please tell me **why** destructuring would affect an object's `this` value. There are many easy work-arounds to this, but I just want to know what is actually going on here. It seems like it should work, but there is something bizarre happening with the `this` scope caused by the destructuring. Anyone know?

Here is a simple object:

```
const user = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 30,
  sayHi() {
    console.log(this); // undefined for foo(), but defined for bar()
    return `hello, ${this.name}`;
  }
};
```

In foo I use destructuring to access the object keys, but the this value is undefined inside of sayHi().

```
const foo = ({ sayHi, name }) => {
  console.log(sayHi()); // hello, [empty string]
  console.log('OUTPUT: foo ->  name', name); // John
};

foo(user);
```

## But here, just passing the object in without destructuring, works as expected and the this value is defined.

```
const bar = person => {
  console.log(person.sayHi()); // hello, John
};

bar(user);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, by destructuring you've created a separate reference to the `sayHi` function. When you then call it from the body of foo, this becomes the context for `this` in the body of `sayHi`.

In the second case, you are calling it as `person.sayHi`, so the context in this case is the containing object - i.e. `person`. Within `sayHi`, `this` is `person`, and name is defined.

There's nothing magical about destructuring, if you manually create a reference to the function you'll get the same effect:

```
const bar = person => {
  const sayHi = person.sayHi;
  console.log(sayHi()); 
};
```

Comment: Ahh, I see now. I knew it was something simple. So I can just use bind() if I want to separate it form the object. Thanks!